# Right mouse click not working on touchpad (Synaptics? / Ubuntu Gnome 17.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, touchpad

I currently have an issue where I can no longer get my right mouse click to work on my laptop trackpad.

70-synaptics.conf: 
https://pastebin.com/rStE3d2F

cat /proc/bus/input/devices:
https://pastebin.com/SD62xeJg

xinput:
https://pastebin.com/CS9WPRr4

evdev: 
https://pastebin.com/HGZeCVPr

I've tried uninstalling synaptics/libinput and reinstalling both at seperate times, and can't get anything to work. I though that evdev was being used, but `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` indicates that I'm using synaptics... and also I think that that is set up right. I'd guess hardware but the trackpoint works fine on my other boot (Windows).

Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: `/proc/...` tells you about the name of the kernel driver. The choice between synaptics/libinput is outside the kernel, it is an X11 thing.  It does not affect the kernel synaptics driver.  A bit confusing I know :-).  If you use Wayland instead of X11, it will always use libinput.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem on my Lenovo laptop running Arch Linux.

I installed the package `xf86-input-synaptics`, restarted system and now it works.

Comment: I realize this is a bit old but I wanted to say that this solved the problem for me as well, right click now works, I am running arch on a Lenovo laptop as well.

Answer (score 1):

In a previous deleted answer, I mentioned how I was able to install libinput on a machine that does not have it. This, of course, was a response to another question on another site and I made an error in answering here instead.

Here is the solution that worked for me.

1. Open GNOME Tweaks (you may need to download it)
2. Go to Mouse and Keyboard
3. Under Mouse Click Emulation, select Area.

Comment: Not a problem! I've no longer got access to this machine but the answer was very elusive, so hopefully, this will still help people.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using only `libinput`?

I see that you are using gnome and maybe is a problem with `wayland`, which does not have a good support for `synaptics`.

Try uninstalling both `synaptics` and `libinput`, then install just `libinput` and reboot your system.

Comment: Unfortunetly that has not worked either. I also tried uninstalling both and the mouse still worked. Though locating synaptics still returns the xorg.confs, I'm unsure if they're deleted anyway though.Could it be that im using evdev?

Comment: Sorry my mistake, they are not there anymore. locate synaptics | grep xorg
just tells me that they are.